# what is the meaning of "it was to be"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

If you are writing in the past tense, does "it was to be" have a different meaning than "it was"?

e.g. "It was to be the first of many sleepless nights." vs "It was the first of many sleepless nights."

Is there any difference in meaning? A friend of mine said that "it was to be" would imply that it didn't actually end up being the first of many sleepless nights whereas "it was" would imply that it was, in fact, the first of many sleepless nights.

If there is no difference in the meaning of "it was to be" and "it was" why would someone use the former phrase? Is it just more formal?

Comment: There is no essential difference in meaning, although they feel different stylistically. And your friend is wrong. *It was to be* means that it *did* happen. (There's no possibility that it didn't.) It's just that it's being discussed from the temporal perspective of the past.

Answer (score 2):

However, 'it was to be' and 'it was' may at times convey the same idea but they cannot be the same everywhere.

Comparing both the examples, I feel a very little difference in them, however, they don't really seem to change the meaning of the sentence.

If I say, '**It was to be** the first of many sleepless nights.' I possibly mean to be more concerned about stating that it was the **beginning** of the sleepless nights and it was the night that turned out to be the first one among all the sleepless nights. Using this phrase, I mean to be a little more expressive about letting my listeners/readers know of where the problem (about experiencing the sleepless nights) started from.

While, if I say, 'It was the first of many sleepless nights.' I possibly don't mean to be concerned about expressing it was the beginning of experiencing the sleepless nights.

**CONTEXT MATTERS**

What your friend said, may at times be true, depending on the context. There may be situations that cannot take both, 'it was to be' and 'it was' to mean the same thing.

e.g. 'The assignment was to be submitted by 10 o'clock but I couldn't even complete it by then.'

In such a situation, 'was to be' implies that something was supposed to happen but didn't actually happen.

'It was to be the first of **many sleepless nights.**'
The words in bold letters clear the context of this sentence and suggest that **it actually was the first sleepless night** as the person saying this sentence states they had many sleepless nights later on and therefore, what your friend says about this particular example is incorrect.

Comment: Hello, Shayan. Whew: reading a subtext 'conveys an attitude of concern for the future' in(to) 'it was to be' sense 'it would prove to be' rather than 'it was intended to be'. I'll think about it. But +1 for putting your finger on the crux of the matter here: _It was to be_ has two senses, _It was intended to be_ (and entailing that it **didn't** eventualise) and _It would prove to be_.

Comment: ... The latter is 'the future in the past' sense.

Answer (score 0):

"It was to be" + [a word other than a past participle] E.g., "It was to be my undoing."

and

"It was to be" + [past participle] E.g., "It was to be assigned on Friday afternoon."

function differently.

Comment: Whilst true that "was to be" can be used in different ways, the question asks about comparative meaning of "was to be" and "was", so this answers a different question.

Answer (score 0):

It has a stylistic value..."it was to be" almost implies fate.
Whereas in a technical document, it would be redundant.

Sounds great in fiction or even a well-flourished autobiography.

Too much though and it gets to be purple prose