# it was to be a time when meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage, be

I was watching a history movie that I saw a new sentence, So I can't meaning that.

"**It was to be a time when** Florence set the standards for European art and culture."

I know be to used for saying arrangement or order but in this sentence doesn't mean.

Comment: It's a history movie - presumably where an introductory voiceover is telling us something about the "time, period, age, era" that's going to be explored in more detail *later in the movie* - but ALL of the movie is about the Past, so that's why it starts with ***It was***. Followed by ***to be*** because the movie hasn't got to that point yet. Contrast this "future within the past" with "Future in the Present" contexts: *The 21st century is to be the age of global civilisation*, or *The 22nd century will be the age of Mars colonisation.*

Comment: So it was to be equals it was going to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the meaning of "it was to be"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502581/what-is-the-meaning-of-it-was-to-be) The sense here, 'it was going to be' / 'it would prove to be', is the 'future in the past' sense.

Comment: Yes, _it was to be_ in this case equals _it was going to be_.

Answer (score 2):

This construction is sometimes used in historical presentation. It is often preceded by an introduction to the theme.

For example. *“The fifteenth century dawned* {introduction}. *It* {the 15th century} *was to be a time ...”*

Here, the reader or listener is invited to place their thoughts at the beginning of the fifteenth century, and to look forward into that century. Hence *“It was* (looking back from our present viewpoint) *to be* (looking forward from the viewpoint of the start of that century) *a time when ...”*